# Why was my Magento question deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I posted a question about Magento which was deleted for absolutely no reason. I have spent about 3 days researching this subject and I know Magento developers that do not know the answer so I'm baffled as to why my question was deleted.

First time on here & genuinely looking for help.

Comment: You clearly don't know how to use this site and he is a respected user. I suspect you are the one who is in error.

Comment: Do not take it personally as it looks...you can repost the question and for this post as Darren noted above, this place is not appropriate.

Comment: how about using: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: posting a link to the question is a good idea (yes some of us can read deleted questions)

Comment: FYI: Using a title of "Such and such sucks at his elected position" is probably not the way to get a positive response. Instead, form an intelligent question and title with evidence, appropriate links, and whatever else may be relevant without sounding like a rant. You will get a much better response that way

Comment: Also, *" I know magento developers that do not know the answer"* this does not mean it's a reasonable question for this site (I don't know if it is since you haven't linked it). I can ask why dogs don't have wings and, even though no veterinarians may be able to answer it, doesn't make it a valid question for SO

Comment: I wouldn't investigate, let him cool down first ;-) I understand you can get angry, but yes it is not the gentleman's way to express it. Just not judging before seeing evidence, because like I said, it has happened before here on SO.

Comment: Try asking an actual question rather than explaining your business.

Comment: So i only just joined...i've viewed this website a lot as google keeps bringing me here while im trying to research the answer. I cannot post the question as i have lost access to it. I wanted to know how to set up absolute pricing for products with multiple attributes in magento 1.8 as the + x amount /+ x percent way doesn't work for us at all.

Comment: The least you could have done before posting would be to read [Ask]  Find out what is allowed, what isnt and how to ask a good question.

Comment: Ok maybe mentioning the business a single time was off topic....however it may of been relevant if someone had experienced the same issue with these types of product. I put a link as other forums have asked me for this whenive posted and i thought it would save time. Hardly reason to lock and delete when i was looking for help.

Comment: asking how to use a CMS is not really a programming question ... if it was wordpress it would likely also be closed ...

Comment: `...other forums...` Note also that SO is not a forum - it is a QA site.  No discussion, no tutoring, no shilly-shallying.  Ask a programming question get an answer.

Comment: Your question was horrendous.  You need to hire a developer.

Answer (score 17):

Your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968015/magento-issue-product-options-doesnt-change-price-on-product-pages) started with "I sell print products online" - followed by a couple of paragraphs that made little sense... followed by a blatant link to your company website hidden behind a bit.ly.

This made it very difficult to believe it was anything but trying to advertise your company - if you have a genuine question and it can be made on topic - then you're welcome to edit your question.

---

You may wish to consider posting to https://magento.stackexchange.com/ - but *make sure* - you stick to its "what's okay to ask" - specifically

> Magento Stack Exchange is for users of and developers working with the Magento e-Commerce platform. Questions which involve custom code or extensions should include relevant code and, where applicable, an indication that the custom coder or extension vendor has been contacted for support.

If you make an attempt to make your question as detailed as possible, and not introduce your company unless someone asks for a link/a screen shot etc... you should be okay.

Comment: thanks for posting the actual question, i would have voted to close and perhaps flagged it had i seen it.

Comment: ok maybe it came across wrong. I wasn't intending to come across as spammy & only linked as i assumed i would be asked for this. I bit.ly'd it as  forum posts turn up in google searches and i didn't want that. I thought i had posted in the correct place.

Comment: @DavidSmith at the end of the day - no harm done. Good luck in solving your problem.

Comment: [I see what you did there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/297442/revisions)

Answer (score 3):

Try reading the Help Webpage, lurking and seeing how things work; then making a contribution to the betterment of this Community.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging

Comment: off topic questions shouldn't be answered

Comment: With respect, i don't really have time to spend lurking on web forums. I was just looking for help with a problem & i know i didn't break any rules & nobody else has had this question answered on here.

With power hungry admins on websites like this there is no wonder the world has such problems when people gain any form of real power.

Comment: I am not part of a "community", i'm not looking for online friends...just answers....and asking a question about magento that nobody seems to have the answer to adds to the "community" in itself.

Comment: @DavidSmith Unfortunately, this isn't how the site works. SO has one of the highest quality standards. And users are expected to lurk for a while to learn the site before they engage.

Comment: It seems this website is staffed by the socially awkward tbh...i just posted a question looking for an answer...is this a dating site for geeks or something? I feel it is wholly unnaceptable for admins to be deleting valid questions which are on topic just because they do not know who i am (who does on the internet!)

Comment: you should go ask on magento's forums probably ... magento questions are likely not programming question (stack overflow is a programming site) ... this is something like asking on the xbox forums why you cannot get your ps-camera to hook up to your ps4 ...

Comment: @DavidSmith it wasn't on topic for SO - please see my updated answer regarding suggested action to successfully post your question.

Comment: Tried magento forums, they seem to think it's acceptable that i have no way to price my products correctly. I ill try insulting more admins as it gets a better response rate than posting questions about magento :)

Comment: Anyway...my research continues...buh bye

Comment: @David: this is not a "dating" community. But it is indeed a community: we post to help each other. You'll have a much better time of it if you show that you're willing to improve your questions, and that you are prepared to treat everyone with respect. Your comments below this answer are not a good start.

Comment: Well nobody helped me :) i have improved the question and moved elsewhere...no doubt nobody will be able to answer it.

Comment: @DavidSmith it is not necessarily a case of not being able to answer your question, it is more likely a case of your question not meeting the standards of this site. (btw, I think I know the answer to your question).

Comment: Just a follow up...i ended up seeking out the developer of the template and asking them....it cost me a fair bit but the issue got fixed. Seems it was just an issue with the template...but i can't give any more info than that :)